# Finding BUTTON of another program

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to make my program click the button of another program. The part I am having issues with is identifying the handle of the button. This is the code I have so far:

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND windowHandle, LPARAM lParam)
{
        cout << "hwnd_Child = " << windowHandle << endl;

        cout<<"WindowId: "<<GetWindowLongPtr(windowHandle, GWLP_ID)<<endl;
        return TRUE;
}
HWND windowHandle = FindWindow(NULL, "nameOfProgramWindow");
EnumChildWindows(windowHandle, EnumChildProc, 0);
```

What is happening so far is that I find the handle of the parent window of the program. With that handle, I use the EnumChildWindows function to go through each of the child windows... and in 1 of those child windows I will have the window which contains 3 buttons, 1 of which is the button I want to press. In the callback function I need to put the GetWindowLongPtr() function to get the ID of the window I am looking for ... there is a problem though...

The problem is that each time I run this program again, the handle and the ID of the window which contains the buttons will change... So I can't use spy++ to get an ID to compare with the ID gotten since The ID changes. I have tested it out even (thats why i have all the "cout" code there);

Question: How do I then identify the window I am looking for in the callback function (and possibly the button I am looking for)?? PLEASE DON'T say spy++ cause the ID and Handle values change every time I open the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The handle is *always* going to change each time that the code runs. Windows dynamically assigns handles. Nothing you or anyone else can do about that. It would be more surprising if it *didn't* change.

And it's no particular conspiracy that the control's ID changes. The only way that stays the same is if it's hard-coded in the original application, most probably via the use of a resource file. But if the programmer dynamically generates the controls at run-time, then there's no reason they would need to use the same ID. Just so long as they keep track of that ID in some kind of data structure if and when they need it.

You may be able to find another property of the button control that is constant—like the caption. But that's certainly not guaranteed. Lots of programs change the caption to reflect the current state.

The application developer is under no obligation to make it easy for another program to mess with the internals of something that does not belong to them.

Have you considered doing this the right way using [UI Automation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee684076.aspx)?

Comment: dude i love your comment, awesome. No I haven't considered it cause I don't know what it is yet, but I will read it right now and see what it is. any tips on UI Automation would be awesome.

Comment: Interesting stuff on UI Automation, seems to be a library of functions that will help me do these processes. It is a good option, however I think that I'll first try to solve the problem using the functions I stated previously and anything else in windows.h and other common libraries... but only cause I have spent quite a bit of time trying and don't want to declare defeat just yet

Comment: Use UIAutomation now.